# Problema con horario y fecha en un calendario creado con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

En un principio, mi código de JavaScript me indicaba la hora de mi zona horaria, así como el día en activo dentro de un calendario. Cuando el reloj marcaba 12:00 am, automáticamente me indicaba el día siguiente. Sin embargo, al quere cambiar la zona horaria usando `timeZone: 'America/New_York'` me di cuenta que cambiaba la zona horaria pero ahora el día cambiaba a la 1:00 am y no a las 12:00 am. Dejando la nueva zona horaria (NY), ¿cómo podría modificarlo para que el día cambie justamente a las 12:00 am y no a la 1:00 am?

Este es mi código JavaScript:

```
const isLeapYear = (year) => {
    return (
      (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0 && year % 400 !== 0) ||
      (year % 100 === 0 && year % 400 === 0)
    );
  };
  const getFebDays = (year) => {
    return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
  };
  let calendar = document.querySelector('.calendar');
  const month_names = [
    'Enero',
    'Febrero',
    'Marzo',
    'Abril',
    'Mayo',
    'Junio',
    'Julio',
    'Agosto',
    'Septiembre',
    'Octubre',
    'Noviembre',
    'Diciembre',
  ];
  let month_picker = document.querySelector('#month-picker');
  const dayTextFormate = document.querySelector('.day-text-formate');
  const timeFormate = document.querySelector('.time-formate');
  const dateFormate = document.querySelector('.date-formate');

  month_picker.onclick = () => {
    month_list.classList.remove('hideonce');
    month_list.classList.remove('hide');
    month_list.classList.add('show');
    dayTextFormate.classList.remove('showtime');
    dayTextFormate.classList.add('hidetime');
    timeFormate.classList.remove('showtime');
    timeFormate.classList.add('hideTime');
    dateFormate.classList.remove('showtime');
    dateFormate.classList.add('hideTime');
  };

  const generateCalendar = (month, year) => {
    let calendar_days = document.querySelector('.calendar-days');
    calendar_days.innerHTML = '';
    let calendar_header_year = document.querySelector('#year');
    let days_of_month = [
      31,
      getFebDays(year),
      31,
      30,
      31,
      30,
      31,
      31,
      30,
      31,
      30,
      31,
    ];
    
    let currentDate = new Date();
    
    month_picker.innerHTML = month_names[month];
    
    calendar_header_year.innerHTML = year;
    
    let first_day = new Date(year, month);


  for (let i = 0; i <= days_of_month[month] + first_day.getDay() - 1; i++) {

      let day = document.createElement('div');

      if (i >= first_day.getDay()) {
        day.innerHTML = i - first_day.getDay() + 1;

        if (i - first_day.getDay() + 1 === currentDate.getDate() &&
          year === currentDate.getFullYear() &&
          month === currentDate.getMonth()
        ) {
          day.classList.add('current-date');
        }
      }
      calendar_days.appendChild(day);
    }
  };

  let month_list = calendar.querySelector('.month-list');
  month_names.forEach((e, index) => {
    let month = document.createElement('div');
    month.innerHTML = `<div>${e}</div>`;

    month_list.append(month);
    month.onclick = () => {
      currentMonth.value = index;
      generateCalendar(currentMonth.value, currentYear.value);
      month_list.classList.replace('show', 'hide');
      dayTextFormate.classList.remove('hideTime');
      dayTextFormate.classList.add('showtime');
      timeFormate.classList.remove('hideTime');
      timeFormate.classList.add('showtime');
      dateFormate.classList.remove('hideTime');
      dateFormate.classList.add('showtime');
    };
  });

  (function () {
    month_list.classList.add('hideonce');
  })();
  document.querySelector('#pre-year').onclick = () => {
    --currentYear.value;
    generateCalendar(currentMonth.value, currentYear.value);
  };
  document.querySelector('#next-year').onclick = () => {
    ++currentYear.value;
    generateCalendar(currentMonth.value, currentYear.value);
  };

  let currentDate = new Date();
  let currentMonth = { value: currentDate.getMonth() };
  let currentYear = { value: currentDate.getFullYear() };
  generateCalendar(currentMonth.value, currentYear.value);

  const todayShowTime = document.querySelector('.time-formate');
  const todayShowDate = document.querySelector('.date-formate');

  const currshowDate = new Date();
  const showCurrentDateOption = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    weekday: 'long',
  };
  const currentDateFormate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'es-MX',
    showCurrentDateOption
  ).format(currshowDate);
  todayShowDate.textContent = currentDateFormate;
  setInterval(() => {
    const timer = new Date();
    const option = {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      second: 'numeric',
      timeZone: 'America/New_York',
    };
    const formateTimer = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-MX', option).format(timer);
    let time = `${`${timer.getHours()}`.padStart(
      2,
      '0'
    )}:${`${timer.getMinutes()}`.padStart(
      2,
      '0'
    )}: ${`${timer.getSeconds()}`.padStart(2, '0')}`;
    todayShowTime.textContent = formateTimer;
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de esto pero te lo comento por si puede ser útil. Puedes buscar otra zona horaria en la que la hora coincida con la de NY, y en la que el cambio de día sea a las 12:00 AM y no  a la 1. No se si funcionará.

Comment: podrías incluir el HTML? Me cuesta imaginar lo que hace cada parte del JS sin eso